# setScaleX() doesn't change actual view size

Tags: android, scaling

I've got a RelativeLayout which is filled with different views (Buttons, Checkboxes...) during runtime.

This container lays within an View called `TwoDScrollView.java`. This is basically a scrollview, but allows me to scroll in both directions. Even diagonal.

It's obviously only scrollable if its content is bigger than itself.

If I now change the scale of my RelativeLayout `container` with the functions `setScaleX` and `setScaleY` it apparently scales correctly.
Problem is, that the actual size of my container doesn't change at all. (`container.getWidth()` and `container.getHeight()`always give the same value)

This is my onClick function:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {       
        int currentPageId = pager.getCurrentItem();
        PageFragment page = (PageFragment)pagePagerAdapater.getItem(currentPageId);
        View view = page.getView();
        RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.container);

        float prevScale = pageZoomFactor[currentPageId];

        if(v.getId() == R.id.bttZoomIn){
            pageZoomFactor[currentPageId] += 0.1f;
        }else if(v.getId() == R.id.bttZoomOut){
            pageZoomFactor[currentPageId] -= 0.1f;
        }else if(v.getId() == R.id.bttZoomReset){
            pageZoomFactor[currentPageId] = 1;
        }

        container.setPivotX(0);
        container.setPivotY(0);
        container.setScaleX(pageZoomFactor[currentPageId]);
        container.setScaleY(pageZoomFactor[currentPageId]);

        android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = (android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams) container.getLayoutParams();
        lp.width = Math.round((container.getWidth() / prevScale) * pageZoomFactor[currentPageId]);
        lp.height = Math.round((container.getHeight() / prevScale) * pageZoomFactor[currentPageId]);

        container.setLayoutParams(lp);

        System.out.println("Width: "+lp.width);
        System.out.println("Height: "+lp.height);
    }
```

As you can see, I already tried to alter the size manually, but I can't seem to get it right. It either get's exponential bigger or smaller than I'd like it to have.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this:

In the mentioned `TwoDScrollView` I changed the `measureChild` function like this:

```
@Override
protected void measureChild(View child, int parentWidthMeasureSpec, int parentHeightMeasureSpec) {
   ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = child.getLayoutParams();
   int childWidthMeasureSpec;
   int childHeightMeasureSpec;

   int scaledWidth = Math.round(lp.width * child.getScaleX());
   int scaledHeight = Math.round(lp.height * child.getScaleY());

   childWidthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(scaledWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
   childHeightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(scaledHeight, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

   child.measure(childWidthMeasureSpec, childHeightMeasureSpec);
 }
```

I hope this helps others who face a similar problem.

Comment: Actually, after testing it a bit it doesn't seem right. After manually altering th size of the layout, android applys the scale again (which makes sence, I guess) and therefore I doubled my zoom.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue, here's how I got it to work.

Firstly, I scaled the child view as opposed to the container. That way, you don't have to try and hack the container to report different sizes. The container's size is just the container's size: what you see on your activity. It's the view it's holding onto that gets bigger or smaller.

However, changing the scale of the child view doesn't cause the child view's reported size to change either. So, I just decided to accept it. Instead, I altered my parent layout's scrollbars so that it would permit scrolling further than the reported size of the view.

So in my parent view, I overwrote the `computeHorizontalScrollRange` and `computeVerticalScrollRange` methods to take into account the extra amount the child view is zoomed:

```
@Override
protected int computeHorizontalScrollRange() {
    return (int)(childView.getWidth() * childView.getScaleX()) + getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();
}

@Override
protected int computeVerticalScrollRange() {
    return (int)(childView.getHeight() * childView.getScaleY()) + getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();
}
```

Then, I just overwrote `scrollTo` to enforce the bounds. (I'm assuming you've got a gesture detector or something to implement scrolling; something to call scrollBy or scrollTo.)

```
@Override
public void scrollTo(int x, int y) {
    if (x < 0) x = 0;
    else {
        int maxWidth = computeHorizontalScrollRange() - getWidth();
        if (maxWidth < 0) x = 0;
        else if (x > maxWidth) x = maxWidth;
    }

    if (y < 0) y = 0;
    else {
        int maxHeight = computeVerticalScrollRange() - getHeight();
        if (maxHeight < 0) y = 0;
        if (y > maxHeight) y = maxHeight;
    }

    super.scrollTo(x, y);
}
```

And that should do the trick.